# Basic pagination issue using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I am trying to make a basic pagination on my website using Jquery. (The code is below). Everything is working perfectly fine, but what I noticed is that it loads all the results from the query then just slice it using 'slice' functions. This basically just hides the extra results in the background. I don't want to load all the results, I want to load only 4 of them, and when the users click the next or the second number, I want to load the next 4 results not loading them all the same time and just slicing them up.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            //Problem about this is that it loads all the images and just slice them up.

            //Declaring variables
            var page = 1;
            var per_page = 4;
            var items = $('.row').length;
            var page_last = Math.ceil(items/per_page);

            //Set Page
            function setPage(page){
                $('.row').slice(0, page * per_page).hide();
                $('.row').slice(page * per_page - per_page, page * per_page).show();
                $('.row').slice(page * per_page).hide();

            }

            //Next Button
            $('.next').click(function(){
                if(page < page_last){
                    $('.links.link_' + page).attr('href', '#').css('color', 'white');
                    page++;
                    $('.links.link_' + page).removeAttr('href').css('color', 'gray');
                    setPage(page);
                }
            });

            //Previous Button
            $('.prev').click(function(){
                if(page > 1){
                    $('.links.link_' + page).attr('href', '#').css('color', 'white');
                    page--;
                    $('.links.link_' + page).removeAttr('href').css('color', 'gray');
                    setPage(page);
                }
            });

            //Generate Page Links
            for( x = 1; x <= page_last; x++){
                if(x == 1){
                    $('.pages').append(' <a style="color:gray" class="links link_' + x + '">' + x + '</a>');

                }else{
                    $('.pages').append(' <a href="#" class="links link_' + x + '">' + x + '</a>');
                }
            }
            //Links Functions

            $('.links').click(function(){
                $('.links.link_' + page).attr('href', '#').css('color', 'white');
                page = $(this).html();
                $('.links.link_' + page).removeAttr('href').css('color', 'gray');
                setPage(page);
            });


            $('.next, .prev').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
            });

            setPage(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what if the results from the query is big? it will load data very slowly. what about using ajax to load data while user click the next or the second number?

Comment: You just load all results and use 'slice' function to hide part of the results. Didn't you mean that?